# Pi-system generating a tail sigma-field

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have the following problem.

Let $(X_n)_{n\in Z_+}$ be a sequence of random variables with values in $\{-1,1\}$. Let $\mathcal{F}:=\sigma(X_0,X_1,...)$ be the product sigma-field on $\{-1,1\}^{Z_+}$ and for all $n\geq 1$, we define $\mathcal{F}_n:=\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},...)$. We also define the tail sigma-field
$\tau:=\cap_{n\geq 1}\mathcal{F}_n$. It is clear that the class $\mathcal{O}$ of open sets of the product topology on $\{-1,1\}^{Z_+}$ is a $\pi$-system that generates $\mathcal{F}$. If we define $T$ as the shift to the left on $\{-1,1\}^{Z_+}$, we also have that, for all $n\geq 1$, $\mathcal{F}_n$ is generated by the $\pi$-system of open sets $T^{-n}\mathcal{O}$. 
My question is the following:

Do we have $\tau=\sigma(\cap_{n\geq 1}T^{-n}\mathcal{O})$?

Thank you very much for your help!